# Database Layout Privileges & Roles

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

Im currently creating a role System for a web Project (PHP/SQL)
To start me of I will have ~5 fixed roles which can be assigned to users. 
And then I got a lot of different privileges.
Now I have to create a table to assign different privileges to different roles and I wonder whats the best way to do so:

1) Table with columns like that:

```
id  | privilege | sysadmin | editor | ... | guest

0   | db_view   | True     | False | ... | False
1   | page_edit | True     | True  | ... | False
...
```

This seems the best solution as Long as there are only five fixed different roles, but is it still practicable when I open the role system to user defined roles in a future version.

2) Table with columns like that:

```
id  | role      | db_view* | page_edit | ... | usermanagement

0   | sysadmin  | True     | True      | ... | True
1   | Editor    | False    | True      | ... | False
...
```

At the end this table will have a great amount of columns - is that a good idea?
2) Table with columns like that:

```
id  | role      | privilege | Value

0   | sysadmin  | page_edit | True
1   | Editor    | page_edit | True
2   | sysadmin  | dbview    | True
3   | Editor    | dbview    | False
...
```

Here it should probably be enough to just create a dataset for privilges who are true. But it would still require a big table.

---

Is there another way? What would be the clearest, most flexible way to create that table?

Which way do you learn when you study database design?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a classic case for a many to many relationship:

```
TblPrivileges
-------------
Privilege_Id (primary key)
Privilege_name
Other privileges related data

TblRoles
--------
Role_Id (primary key)
Role_Name
Other role related data

TblPrivilegesToRoles
--------------------
PTR_Privilege_Id (reference privilege id in tblPrivileges)
PTR_Role_Id (reference role id in tblRoles)
```

In table `TblPrivilegesToRoles` the primary key should be both columns.

Comment: Thank you! I compleadly forgot about that method.